# How to define a bernoulli density function?

Tags: r, bernoulli-probability

The following is the funciton defined for bernoulli distribution. I am a new R user. I am not quite well-understand the following codes.

```
dbernoulli <- function(x, prob=0.5) {
dbinom(x, size=1, prob=prob)
 }

dbernoulli(y, prob=0.7)
```

I thought in the defined function, we have pre-determined the argument `prob` as `0.5` , so why can we change it to `0.7` when we use the defined function? Is these codes resonable? Can I correct it as follows?

```
dbernoulli <- function(x, prob) {
dbinom(x, size=1, prob=prob)
 }

dbernoulli(y, prob=0.7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `function(x, prob=0.5)` what you say is:

create a function that receives two parameters,

- `x`, with no default value
- and `prob`, with the default value of `0.5`.

Hence, if you call the function `dbernoulli(y)` it will assign `x = y` and because you didn't pass a value for `prob`, it will assign `prob = 0.5` because that's the default value you've defined for it.

Now, if you remove the default value for `prob`, like `function(x, prob)`, then you'll always be required to state the prob you want to use when calling the function, as in `dbernoulli(y,prob = 0.7)`.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning partial argument matching and passing arguments by name vs placement. i.e. `dbernoulli(p=0.7, x=y)` is equivalent to `dbernoulli(y, 0.7)`.